# .htaccess let's you view .jpg while prevents from viewing others

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName= [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/index.html [R,L]
```

This is how my .htaccess file looks like. My problem:
If cookie is not set, it still lets you view .jpg files (what I don't want to happen)(maybe other image files too, dunno), while it redirects to index.html from .docx, .pptx, .sfk etc. So I want to know how to force redirect on accessing images (at least .jpg, .png, .gif)?

Comment: i don't think this is the best approach - store the images outside the web root then use a php script to show them to logged in users (cookie check in php).

Comment: Be aware that it's trivial for a user to inject a cookie themselves. If you're not checking something _inside_ the cookie is valid against information the server holds, you're not adding any security at all. One solution is to have a php file which serves files after checking credentials eg `showfile.php?FileId=123` or `showfile.php?FileName=ANC.jpg`. This allows you to keep the real files outside the document root and properly restrict access

Comment: Won't this cause a redirect loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a hotlink prevention tactic. If your trying to prevent outside access, such as other websites using your images.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://mysite.com/nolinking.gif [L]
```

or you could serve up a 403 error instead..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

but in all you could run into conflict using images on your own site in the long run if you try other methods. I dunno exactly what your attempting to accomplish so I am only speculating.